# Photoshop filter duplication

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, effects, filter

Im new to the Graphic Design Stack Exchange but I am trying to duplicate the filter used in this picture in photoshop.  I was close using Pixelate < Pointalize but it still doesnt work.

[image: Photo im trying to duplicate filter for]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is by using overlay layer with texture.

Heres some textures you could use http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/freebies/free-pack-of-12-distressed-halftone-pattern-textures

Just put it on the top of your current picture layer and find suitable blending mode and opacity and you'l be all good